# Assign default value to first dropdown element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have dropdown in my view

Here is code of dropdown

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{l("LandlordType")}}</label>
    <p-dropdown [options]="landlordTypes" autoWidth="false"  [style]="{'width':'100%'}" name="type" [autoWidth]="true" [(ngModel)]="landlord.landlordTypeId"></p-dropdown>
</div>
```

Here is how I populate it

I send request to server and get all landlord types

```
getLandlordTypes(): void {
    this._landlordTypesService.getLandlordTypesDropdownValues().subscribe(result => {
        result.items.forEach(value => {
            this.landlordTypes.push({ label: value.name, value: value.id });
        });
        this.landlord.landlordTypeId = result.items[0].id;
    });
}
```

and call this method in `ngOnInit`

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getLandlordTypes();
}
```

But when I open modal with this dropdown my first element got `id = 0`, instead of `11` for example. As I understood I need to push default value somehow to it. How I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. Looks like you got your bindings wrong. Your dropdown options values should be binded entire object.

You should replace

```
this.landlord.landlordTypeId = result.items[0].id;
```

With

```
this.landlord = result.items[0];
```

This is how getLandlordTypes() method should look like:

```
getLandlordTypes(): void {
  this._landlordTypesService.getLandlordTypesDropdownValues().subscribe(result => {
    result.items.forEach(value => {
      this.landlordTypes.push({ label: value.name, value: value.id });
    });
    this.landlord = result.items[0];
  });
}
```

And on your HTML, use set your 2-way data bindings to `[(ngModel)]="landlord` instead.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>{{l("LandlordType")}}</label>
  <p-dropdown [options]="landlordTypes" autoWidth="false"  [style]="{'width':'100%'}" name="type" [autoWidth]="true" [(ngModel)]="landlord"></p-dropdown>
</div>
```